# Truncating Date Filter in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a date Filter in Tableau, but the lower bound is defaulting for Q1 in the year 1900 (notice how the range for 2020 - 2021 is super small). Is there a way to adjust this? Can I set a lower-bound for the date range, so the user cannot scroll past say Q1 2016?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make a copy of your date filter, place it on the filter card and select 'range of dates' then select 'starting date' and choose input the date minimum.